# Shininess with Haskell Opengl

Tags: haskell, opengl

I have done numerous graphics with Haskell OpenGL. They are in my repo here: [opengl-examples](https://github.com/stla/opengl-examples) (the gallery is not exhaustive). However I have a problem: when I use `materialShininess` nothing happens. It there something to enable in order to have the shininess ?

Here is an example of one of my prog. It it not complete but I hope it's enough to identify the issue.

```
module CompoundFiveTetrahedra2
  where
import           CompoundFiveTetrahedra.Data
import           Control.Monad                     (when)
import qualified Data.ByteString                   as B
import           Data.IORef
import           Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.Capture (capturePPM)
import           Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL
import           Graphics.UI.GLUT
import           Text.Printf
import           Utils.ConvertPPM
import           Utils.OpenGL                      (negateNormal)
import           Utils.Prism

blue,red,green,yellow,purple,white,black :: Color4 GLfloat
blue   = Color4 0   0   1   1
red    = Color4 1   0   0   1
green  = Color4 0   1   0   1
yellow = Color4 1   1   0   1
white  = Color4 1   1   1   1
black  = Color4 0   0   0   1
purple = Color4 0.5 0   0.5 1

display :: IORef GLfloat -> IORef GLfloat -> IORef GLfloat -> IORef GLdouble
        -> IORef GLint -> IORef GLfloat -> DisplayCallback
display rot1 rot2 rot3 zoom capture angle = do
  clear [ColorBuffer, DepthBuffer]
  r1 <- get rot1
  r2 <- get rot2
  r3 <- get rot3
  z <- get zoom
  a <- get angle
  i <- get capture
  loadIdentity
  (_, size) <- get viewport
  resize z size
  rotate a $ Vector3 1 1 1
  rotate r1 $ Vector3 1 0 0
  rotate r2 $ Vector3 0 1 0
  rotate r3 $ Vector3 0 0 1
  mapM_ (drawEdge blue)   (edges!!0)
  mapM_ (drawEdge red)    (edges!!1)
  mapM_ (drawEdge green)  (edges!!2)
  mapM_ (drawEdge yellow) (edges!!3)
  mapM_ (drawEdge purple) (edges!!4)
  mapM_ (drawVertex blue)   vertices1
  mapM_ (drawVertex red)    vertices2
  mapM_ (drawVertex green)  vertices3
  mapM_ (drawVertex yellow) vertices4
  mapM_ (drawVertex purple) vertices5
  when (i > 0) $ do
    let ppm = printf "tetrahedra%04d.ppm" i
        png = printf "tetrahedra%04d.png" i
    (>>=) capturePPM (B.writeFile ppm)
    convert ppm png True
    capture $~! (+1)
  swapBuffers

drawVertex :: Color4 GLfloat -> Vertex3 GLfloat -> IO ()
drawVertex col v =
  preservingMatrix $ do
    translate $ toVector v
    materialDiffuse Front $= col
    renderObject Solid $ Sphere' 0.03 30 30
  where
    toVector (Vertex3 x y z) = Vector3 x y z

drawEdge :: Color4 GLfloat -> (Vertex3 GLfloat, Vertex3 GLfloat) -> IO ()
drawEdge col (v1,v2) = do
  let cylinder = prism v1 v2 30 0.03
  renderPrimitive Quads $ do
    materialDiffuse Front $= col
    mapM_ drawQuad cylinder
  where
    drawQuad ((w1,w2,w3,w4),n) = do
      normal $ negateNormal n
      vertex w1
      vertex w2
      vertex w3
      vertex w4

resize :: Double -> Size -> IO ()
resize zoom s@(Size w h) = do
  viewport $= (Position 0 0, s)
  matrixMode $= Projection
  loadIdentity
  perspective 45.0 (w'/h') 1.0 100.0
  lookAt (Vertex3 0 0 (-3 + zoom)) (Vertex3 0 0 0) (Vector3 0 1 0)
  matrixMode $= Modelview 0
  where
    w' = realToFrac w
    h' = realToFrac h

keyboard :: IORef GLfloat -> IORef GLfloat -> IORef GLfloat -> IORef GLint
         -> KeyboardCallback
keyboard rot1 rot2 rot3 capture c _ =
  case c of
    'r' -> rot1 $~! subtract 1
    't' -> rot1 $~! (+1)
    'f' -> rot2 $~! subtract 1
    'g' -> rot2 $~! (+1)
    'v' -> rot3 $~! subtract 1
    'b' -> rot3 $~! (+1)
    'c' -> capture $~! (+1)
    'q' -> leaveMainLoop
    _   -> return ()

mouse :: IORef GLdouble -> MouseCallback
mouse zoom button keyState _ =
  case (button, keyState) of
    (LeftButton, Down)  -> zoom $~! (+0.1)
    (RightButton, Down) -> zoom $~! subtract 0.1
    _                   -> return ()

idle :: IORef GLfloat -> IdleCallback
idle angle = do
  angle $~! (+ 2)
  postRedisplay Nothing

main :: IO ()
main = do
  _ <- getArgsAndInitialize
  _ <- createWindow "Five tetrahedra"
  initialDisplayMode $= [RGBAMode, DoubleBuffered, WithDepthBuffer]
  clearColor $= black
  materialAmbient Front $= black
  materialShininess Front $= 80 -- THIS DOES NOT WORK
  lighting $= Enabled
  light (Light 0) $= Enabled
  position (Light 0) $= Vertex4 0 0 (-100) 1
  ambient (Light 0) $= white
  diffuse (Light 0) $= white
  specular (Light 0) $= white
  depthFunc $= Just Lequal
  depthMask $= Enabled
  shadeModel $= Smooth
  rot1 <- newIORef 0.0
  rot2 <- newIORef 0.0
  rot3 <- newIORef 0.0
  zoom <- newIORef 0.0
  capture <- newIORef 0
  angle <- newIORef 0.0
  displayCallback $= display rot1 rot2 rot3 zoom capture angle
  reshapeCallback $= Just (resize 0)
  keyboardCallback $= Just (keyboard rot1 rot2 rot3 capture)
  mouseCallback $= Just (mouse zoom)
  idleCallback $= Just (idle angle)
  mainLoop
```

Do I miss something to enable the shininess ?

## EDIT

Here is an example with the R package `rgl`, which is also a wrapper to OpenGL. Look at the white part on the spheres. I cannot achieve that with Haskell.

[image]

Comment: Really cool examples. I'm not an OpenGL expert, but I played with it a while back. iirc, you need to create a shader which involves compiling a bit of code in a special shader language. see Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.Shaders.

Comment: Thank you @user2297560. I'm not an expert as well and yet I dont know whar are the shaders.

Comment: It might be working but just not do what you're expecting, and might not have any effect in the example scene you've created.  Shininess is just about the size of the specular point in lighting, it doesn't create reflections or anything.  [More here](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/128310-Shininess)

Comment: Thanks @luqui. Unfortunately it's not easy for me to understand such discussions. .By the way I'm also using the R package rgl which is also a wrapper of OpenGL and I'm wondering how the author deals with the shininess. Unfortuntaly the code is hard.To come back to your comment, I should say that I'm a bit lost with all stuff dealing with the lighting. I often try at random until I reach what I want.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I don't think that's necessarily a bad way -- you can read about the math of lighting but I'm not sure it gives an intuition for what it looks like in practice.  Though it does help to know what the different terms mean.  Might be worth it to read a tutorial specifically about lighting [like this one](http://www.falloutsoftware.com/tutorials/gl/gl8.htm) (I haven't read it, just skimmed it) to get a structured sense of the different components.

Comment: Thanks for the link @luqui. Looks not bad. I agree it's necessary to read a tuto at a certain step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: Try shininess of 1.0 to see the difference more clearly at low resolutions.

The shininess parameter affects the sharpness of specular lighting, so you need to turn this type of lighting on for your materials by giving them a specular color.  (By default, the specular color is black, so the effect of the shininess parameter will not be visible.)  You'll also want to reduce the shininess value for this scene, because it's too high to be very visible.

Try:

```
materialSpecular Front $= white
materialShininess Front $= 1.0
```

and you'll start to see white highlights, particularly along the curved edges of your shape.  The flat faces will also reflect some white light, but only when they are nearly perpendicular to a line that's mid-angle between the viewer and the light source -- it's a little complicated.

Note that the specular color of most materials is taken to be some "multiple" of white (i.e., somewhere between black for a perfectly dull material to white for the shiniest materials in the scene).  The only materials with tinted specular color would be colored metals, like gold or bronze.

Some additional notes:

- You're using old-style OpenGL 2.1 shading, not "modern OpenGL", so you don't have to worry so much about the "shaders" that @user2297560 is talking about.  OpenGL 2.1 comes with built-in shaders to do basic shading; with modern OpenGL, you have to build everything from scratch.
- As @luqui mentioned, if you're looking for materials that actually *reflect* other parts of the scenes, this kind of shininess won't help you.

Here is the difference.  Your original code on the left, the settings above on the right, on your "compoundfivetetrahedra" example.  It'll look better if you increase the size of the window.

[image: Original code (left) and with specular=white and shininess=1.0 on right.]

Note that it works better on curved surfaces.  Here's your cylinder example, using:

```
materialShininess Front $= 5
materialSpecular Front $= white
```

You can see the shininess on the closer sphere.

[image: Cylinder example, showing shininess on one end]

Comment: Thanks. Ive tried quickly but didn't see any difference. I will try later on a sphere. I didnt know "model OpenGL".

Comment: Sorry but I didn't manage to get the whiteness. I've edited my post to include an example to show what I mean.

Comment: I added a couple of examples from your code to show the effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Ill try later. That's very kind.

Comment: Hmm sorry but I didn't manage yet. I've tried with the horse saddle, which is very curved. Where do you put this code exactly ? Is it ok to put it in the main function ? Or should I put it where I do `renderPrimitive` ?

Comment: Oh wait I think I get it now. Thats because I had `specular (Light 0) $= black`, and I switched to `specular (Light 0) $= white`. Now I see a difference (slight difference by the way).